# 14.04_x64 / Nvidia GT 240 , HUGE font notificaton at greeter and in naulitus after log-in

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, fonts, lightdm

I've been using 12.04 for a long time - excellent version indeed, I decided to try 14.04 today.  Installing without any problems.

My VGA is Nvidia GT240 (legacy one), Nouveau display driver is fine, font display is normal.

Then, I decided to install Nvidia legacy binary driver 304.117 updates (proprietary) instead of default Nouveau display driver.

Problems come after rebooting

1. At Greeter a notification "Wired connection 1 -Connected" pop up but with a **HUGE font**.
   [image]
2. After log-in HUGE FONT symptom still remains at some parts - for example, Calendar, Desktop shortcut and Files explorer.
   [image]

within few seconds, 10 to 15 may be, there is a screen blink but HUGE font still remains. I have to log out then log in again to have normal font in all parts of system.

Changing driver, even an update one form ppa:xorg-edgersnot doesn't solve the problem.

Any advices or solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: I just installed UbuntuGnome 14.04, same symptom remains. Is it something about new Xserver version not compatible with Nvidia GT240 card?

Comment: **SOLVED**, just changed display connection cable from HDMI to DVI.

Comment: No need to change the name to "solved". If you think your solution could be useful to others, you could answer the question yourself :)