# Desktop and Nautilus fonts suddenly HUGE

Tags: unity, nautilus, fonts

I am running 14.04 (x64) with an nVidia card.
About a week ago, the desktop and Nautilus fonts both ballooned in size, and I have been unable to find compiz or unity settings that address this.

Anybody know what might have caused this or what I might try to reign those font sizes down to useful scale?  It is worth noting that the icons also scaled up in keeping with the fonts. I can resize the icons in Nautilus, but the fonts remain crazy huge.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of this issue? Upload it somewhere and I'll link it here for you.

Comment: I found the same issued. https://askubuntu.com/questions/455608/14-04-x64-nvidia-gt-240-huge-font-notificaton-at-greeter-and-in-naulitus-aft . Still don't know how to fix it except using DVI to connect the monitor instead of HDMI however "Huge font" might be gone but weird hinting font happens. Now I'm on 12.04 and will only upgrade to the next LTS after 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnome-tweak-tool to set the font sizes.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

I don't know why they would change on there own however.

Comment: Seems like tweak tool changes all font size, except for the font used in desktop icons

Answer (score 0):

on my Ubuntu, the font size scaling was set to 1.6 (suddenly, from one day to another). I could change this setting after installing [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/).

see [How do I change fonts and adjust their size?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19770/how-do-i-change-fonts-and-adjust-their-size)

BurninLeo